# Zend Framework Module Setup

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

I'm trying to setup a module in the Zend Framework.  Right now all I want is for it to go to my `summary.phtml` page, which will display `Hello World`.
I have setup the directory structure under my `module` directory as follows:

[image: Directory Structure]

My files are as follows:

> module.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
        'controllers' => array(
                'invokables' => array(
                        'BlindQC\Controller\BlindQC' => 'BlindQC\Controller\BlindQCController',
                ),
        ),
        // The following section is new and should be added to your file
        'router' => array(
                'routes' => array(
                        'blinqc' => array(
                                'type' => 'Literal',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'route' => '/summary',
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'BlindQC\Controller',
                                                'controller' => 'BlindQC',
                                                'action' => 'summary',
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'view_manager' => array(
                'template_path_stack' => array(
                        'blindqc' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
                ),
        ),
);
```

---

> BlindQCController.php

```
<?php
namespace BlindQC\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class BlindQCController extends AbstractActionController{
    public function summaryAction(){

    }
};
```

---

> summary.phtml

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

---

> autoload_classmap.php

```
<?php
return array();
```

---

> Module.php

```
<?php
namespace BlindQC;

class Module {
    public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
        return array(
                'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(__DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',),
                'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                        'namespaces' => array(__NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,),
                ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig() {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

---

I also modified my project's `application.config.php` to include my module:

```
// This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'UIExperiment',
        'Developer',
        'User',
        'Project',
        'Report',
        'ProjectFamily', 
        'FMEProcessManager', 
        'BlindQC'
),
```

---

When I try to go to the summary route (`/blindqc/summary`) I get a 404.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was change the route in `module.config.php` to `/blindqc/summary` and rename `view/blindqc/blindqc` to `view/blind-qc/blind-qc` in my directory structure.